# Can't get data when form loads via javascript in yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

In salary form I want to get data from ratechart model in certain textfields when the form loads.

In Ratechart Controller I've added

```
public $rateid = '1';

public function actionGetForRatechart($rateid)
    {
        $rates = Ratechart::find()->where(['rc_id'=> $rateid])->asArray()->one();
        echo Json::encode($rates);
    }
```

In salary _form I've added the following javascript code -

```
<?php
$script = <<<EOD
$(window).load(function(){
    $.get('index.php?r=salary/ratechart/get-for-ratechart',{ rateid : rateid }, function(data){
    alert(data);
    var data = $.parseJSON(data);
});
EOD;
?>
```

It's not giving any result. It's the same question as [Load data to a form from a different model in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38067065/load-data-to-a-form-from-a-different-model-in-yii2). Please help.

Comment: Are you sure your URL is correct? URL should be in format controller/action i.e ratechart/get-for-ratechart and not salary/ratechart/get-for-ratechart, unless salary is a module name.

Comment: salary is a module name dear.

Comment: Check for the errors in console if any

Comment: Have you tried visiting the actual url to check the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dear you forgot to `registerJs()` in view. and your js syntax is wrong.please use this.

```
<?php

$script = <<<EOD
  $(window).load(function(){
  $.get(
  'index.php?r=salary/ratechart/get-for-ratechart',
  { rateid : 1 }, 
  function(data){
      alert(data);
      var data = $.parseJSON(data);
  }
  );
});
EOD;

$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Comment: Thank You. Working perfectly.